# Android: Where are files saved?

Tags: android, save, fileoutputstream

I'm programming an app, which needs to store data in a textfile.

I'm using FileOutputStream:

```
outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
outputStream.write(data.getBytes());
outputStream.close();
```

My question is: Where is the file saved?

I can't find it anywhere...

For debugging, I'm using a nexus7.

Comment: Go to this:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735159/saving-files-from-app-android?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735159/saving-files-from-app-android?rq=1)

Comment: it can be in `/data/data/yourpackagename/` folder

Comment: You should read this [explanation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's stored under `/data/data/<your app>` by default. But unless you have rooted device, you have no access to this folder from device. But you can take a look on your file by using `DDMS` from the `Android SDK` (at the `android-sdk\tools` folder)

Answer (score 0):

If You are using Context.MODE_PRIVATE it is stored in application data directory and you do not have access to them from file manager

Answer (score 0):

`/data/data/your.app.package.name/files`, but note this can be device dependent.. you can find it in eclipse by typing DDMS and then go to file explorer and then follow the above path

Answer (score 0):

writes to a file in your internal directory
/data/data/pacakage/files